# Display live scores

Tags: c#

I am planning to design a website which displays the live scores of matches(NBA, AFL) etc. I would like to get scores, store them in my database and then display in my website. How can I accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Sandeep.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Sandeep. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you need to decide how you're going to get the data. Is there a webservice that you can query? A document/webpage you can parse to get the information? Are you going to write a speech recognition device to interpret results from the radio or will you type it in by hand.

Then you need to get your database up and running, and whatever is reading your data (maybe it could be a windows service) can write the data into the database. Something like SQLExpress is quite good to try out.

Once you've got that you'll need to decide on your technology, ASP.NET or Silverlight are some good examples. You'll want to create some controls and then databind to the results from your database, which you could obtain using SQL expressions.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I did not find any webservice which does this. I feel parsing a webpage is not that flexible. Please let me know if I can implement this some other way.

Comment: @Sandeep: If there is no web-service available, I'm afraid your only other option is to crawl online records. This can be frustrating, but not always.

Comment: @Sandeep: Parsing a webpage isn't very flexible and possibly not entirely legal. If you do go this route I'd make sure you check with the site owner first.

Comment: @Sandeep: Indeed, I'd agree with Cory. I was throwing up examples to get more information on what you'd really like to do. If you don't have access to RSS feeds however it is going to be quite difficult for you to do in a 'nice' and 'flexible' way.